# Issue with Android Support Library 23.2.1 AppBarLayout setExpanded

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-support-design

I have upgraded Android Support Library from `23.1.1` to `23.2.1` and `AppBarLayout` `setExpanded` method is no longer working as it used to.

I have `CollapsingToolbarLayout` that occupies whole screen, and below it there is `NestedScrollView` holding other views. Swiping up and down completely collapses/expands toolbar layout, thus showing or hiding scroll view with content.

Manual swipes work fine, but I also have button that triggers `AppBarLayout` `setExpanded` method with `true/false` parameters to automatically collapse/expand toolbar. With version `23.1.1` this method also works properly, but with `23.2.1` only first collapsing of the toolbar will show content in below scroll view, all subsequent collapses will not. Triggering `setExpanded(true)` method when toolbar is collapsed will show content of my scroll view, and expanding animation will work as it is supposed to work.

Issue can be reproduced on devices/emulators with API's 22 and lower.

Any ideas how I might fix this behavior in `23.2.1` library?

---

Basic example that exhibits above behavior:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.test.displaym;

import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void btnClick(View v)
    {
        View iv = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        AppBarLayout bar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);

        if (iv.getTop() == 0) bar.setExpanded(false);
        else bar.setExpanded(true);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.test.displaym.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            >

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/image_view"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/page_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/page"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text = "Some text\n12345\n"
                      android:orientation="vertical">
            </TextView>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scroll"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="btnClick"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.displaym"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
}
```

The rest of project files are just the same as in base Android Studio project with empty activity.

- Screen snapshot of correct behavior - text should be visible all the time during collapsing/expanding animation triggered with `SCROLL` button. It should not be visible only when toolbar (blue area) fully covers the screen.

[image]

- Screen snapshot of broken behavior - text is not visible during toolbar collapsing animation triggered by `SCROLL` button.

[image]

*Red arrow in above screen snapshots shows area of the screen that should be observed.*

Comment: Similar issue appears with support library 23.3.0. Reported as https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=205960

Comment: Strangely enough, disabling animation of setExpanded (`bar.setExpanded(false, false)`) seems to work properly. So the issue/bug is probably in the animation code of support library(?).

Comment: @Sevle That would be correct observation. It doesn't help much, though, because animation effect is what I am after here :)

Comment: Issue has been fixed with 23.4.0 library

Answer (score -1):

Something changed regarding fitsSystemWindows.

Remove this attribute from AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Leave only in CoordinatorLayout.

Answer (score -1):

remove all

> android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

on child layout and only Parent RelativeLayout has it.

And edit CollapsingToolbarLayout to :

```
           <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|enterAlways">
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks, but this does not solve scrolling content issue. Also `snap|enterAlways` flags drastically change scrolling behavior in a way that does not fit my purpose.